# Improve accuracy of my DNN model

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset on which I train a DNN model.

My dataset is like this (single example row):

```
hash          name  surname  datetime                  total  nb_success  nb_loss 
axBBdnn78     aaa   bbb      2016-01-01 00:01:26       50.00   1           2
```

I replaced the header names (confidentiality), but they are all important. The value I try to predict is the `state` column (present on the dataset), which can take 2 values: 'ok' and 'nok'.

By doing some preparation on the dataset and one-encoding the string with this code:

```
data = data.select_dtypes(exclude=['number']).apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform).join(data.select_dtypes(include=['number']))
```

I then got my final training set, which looks like this:

```
hash  name  surname  datetime  total  nb_success  nb_loss 
1696  4     37       01        50.00  1            2
```

I then use the following Keras DNN model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_shape=(7,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1)) # 2 outputs possible (ok or nok)
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But, neither my loss decreases, or my accuracy increases.

```
5000/5000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.5070 - acc: 0.4930 - val_loss: 0.4900 - val_acc: 0.5100
Epoch 2/10
5000/5000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.5054 - acc: 0.4946 - val_loss: 0.5100 - val_acc: 0.4900
Epoch 3/10
5000/5000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.5112 - acc: 0.4888 - val_loss: 0.4140 - val_acc: 0.5860
Epoch 4/10
5000/5000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.4900 - acc: 0.5100 - val_loss: 0.4660 - val_acc: 0.5340
```

I tried several other loss functions as well as other optimizers, but each time I only achieve roughly 50% accuracy (so, nothing since the output is 2 classes).

I have two questions:

1. Is my one-encoding method correct?
2. Which part do I miss for the model to actually train/converge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have label-encoded your data but not one-hot encoded it. For every label you have in each of your features you need to create one binary label.

E.g.: If you have 4 names than you need 3 binary labels that represent the 4 possible states.

You can use Scikit-learn´s OneHotEncoder: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

One of the reasons for this is that right now name #37 is "more" or "higher" than name #36 or #10 or #5 which doesn´t make any sense (since these are categorical values rather than continuous ones)

2. On your last Dense layer you need to use sigmoid as the activation function.

One more thing: You might need to increase your models size. And you have two lines of `model.add(Activation('relu'))` in your code.

Comment: Would [LabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html) be of better use here?

Comment: As far as I know LabelBinarizer does transform your categorical data to dummy variables but not to one-hot-encoded data. One-hot means you have one less binary label than categorical values. This is necessary to avoid the dummy variable trap: http://www.algosome.com/articles/dummy-variable-trap-regression.html I use 1. the LabelEncoder then 2. the OneHotEncoder and then 3. I manually remove one binary label (to avoid said trap). There might be easier ways. It´s simply my workflow.